# How to use SQL to query the metadata in Microsoft Office Access? Like SQL Server's sys.tables, sys.columns etc

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, metadata

I'm totally new to Access but I'm familiar with SQL Server. I want to know if it's possible to use SQL to query the metadata in Microsoft Office Access? Like SQL Server's sys.tables, sys.columns etc. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
SELECT Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE Left([Name],1)<>"~"
AND Left([Name],4)<>"MSys"
AND Type In (1,4,6)
ORDER BY Name;
```

for table names

[list of table names](http://nm1m.blogspot.de/2005/06/ms-access-list-table-names.html) and  [a list of database objects](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=99146&highlight=table%20names)

Comment: Elaborate your answer.