# SSIS - Check OLE DB source schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, ssis

I have a ETL project that I need to load data from some 50K Access .MDB databases in a folder to sql server. Problem with those 50K databases files is that they have different schemas and I need the ETL process to be able to identify the differences and respond correctly.

For example, in some of the .MDB files there are table A, B and C. However in some other tables there are only table A and B (Same table A and B as compared to the other tables, just table C is missing). I need to put a check on each OLE DB source to see what tables are there to achieve logic like IF table A  exists, load table A, otherwise, bypass the load.

I've done my googling and searched SO but all the error handling or check methods I could find are for the execute SQL task or data conversion task. So if anyone could shed some light on solution to my above case, I would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a job for BIML. BIML lets you build packages on the fly based on metadata

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell - SSIS assumes that metadata does not change.
However, with some tricks, this restriction can be reduced; below is the list of suggested tricks:

1. Test for existence of specific table (see example here [How to use SQL to query the metadata in Microsoft Office Access? Like SQL Server's sys.tables, sys.columns etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350488/how-to-use-sql-to-query-the-metadata-in-microsoft-office-access-like-sql-server)) and based on the result - do conditional execution of the following tasks.
2. All SQL requests to MS Access tables should have **DelayValidation** property set to **True**. Reason - postpone SQL command validation from package start to specific task execution. Some tasks (for missing tables) will not be executed; thus, it will not be validated and will not fire validation error.