# How Can I Tell the Primary Key of a Table of a MSAccess Table (from Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, ms-access

I'm using access2csv on Linux. How can I determine the PK of a table?

I've exported to a csv and using csvstat (from csvkit). The closest thing I've found is to look for "uniq. values = recordcount" but some false positives could come up. Does anyone have any (other) suggestions?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: primary key is defined by design, without metadata and only data there is no way to find primary key also a primary kay can be composed of many columns

Comment: Thanks Nahuel. I'm aware of the design process though I was hoping that there could be a cli (similar to mdb-tools, access2csv) that could query MSysNavPaneGroups and the other system objects that (should?) store the PK/column constraint(s) info.

Comment: maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350488/how-to-use-sql-to-query-the-metadata-in-microsoft-office-access-like-sql-server

Comment: Thanks but not quite. Looks like the table info. is stored in mSysObjects.lvprop (.http://jabakobob.net/mdb/lvprop.html)